# Averaging raster layers in QGIS, values changed, but image looks the same?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, average

I am trying to average two raster layers together, but am getting results that are really confusing me, which is making me even question if an average is actually what I want to do to begin with. I will explain further conceptually now.

I have these two rasters representing "cooling effect" resonating from green space footprints, decaying as distance away from the site increases, with the site itself having the highest cooling influence:

1)
[image]

and the scale:
[image]

2)
[image]

and the scale:
[image]

And so I basically want to "blend" these rasters together with the idea of showing how the cooling effect between both of these green spaces interact. What I thought I should do is simply average these two rasters together. What I was envisioning I would see in the output averaged raster would be a relatively similar image, with both green space sites still protruding out visible as the highest value hotspots, with a "blending" effect shown in between.

I simply entered this into the Raster Calculator:

```
("Raster1" + "Raster2") / 2
```

However, when I actually average these two rasters together using the raster calculator in QGIS I see this:

[image]

with this scale:
[image]

This is not what I was expecting at all. This looks just like raster 1. I see the scale values are different, but I am confused why this looks to be the exact same thing. I see one hotspot there, but the hotspot from raster 2 is totally hidden, and I cannot seem to understand why. I want to still see both hotspots. I really though an average would be what I needed to blend these two rasters together, but I am feeling I am totally misunderstanding what an average would even accomplish here. Also, we can forget the context of green space cooling here, and perhaps just approach this as two rasters with a continuous value that can be anything!

My question is, should I even be trying an average here or should I be trying another method if I want to blend these rasters together but still be able to make out both hotspots?

Comment: Please show the raster calculator formula that you used.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I just updated my post with the raster calculator formula I used.

Comment: More info is needed.  Please describe your 2 input rasters in more detail, including their respective coordinate reference systems.  Also what do your input and output data values represent?  Those are some awfully large numbers!  Finally, load all three rasters into the table of contents and then click in various screen locations, using the Identify tool.  It will return the value of all three rasters at each location.  You should expect the output raster values to be the average of the inputs.  Does that happen?